# C++ Interface Implementation and Subclassed Object Instatiation

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclassing

**Update**
The actual context is that I need to create a package to submit to NIST, trying to test a Facial Recognition Algorithm I am working on. The API to use can be found at [NIST API](https://www.nist.gov/sites/default/files/documents/2018/04/03/frvt_11_concept_and_api_3.0.pdf) and the project to git is at [git project](https://github.com/usnistgov/frvt)

Some code to make a summary of the scenario:

**a.h** - interface `A`, composed by pure virtual methods and one static method (frvt11.h at NIST project)

```
class A {
   public:
      virtual ~A() {}
      virtual void pure_virtual_method_a() = 0;
      virtual void pure_virtual_method_b() = 0;
      static int static_method();
}
```

**b.h** - header file for `b.cpp`, where interface `A`'s methods are implemented

```
#include "a.h"

class B : A {
   public:
      void pure_virtual_method_a();
      void pure_virtual_method_b();
      static int static_method();
}
```

**b.cpp** - Implementation of interface `A`'s methods.

```
#include "b.h"

void pure_virtual_method_a() {/*implementation*/};
void pure_virtual_method_b() {/*implementation*/};
int static_method() {/*implementation*/};
```

**c.cpp** - A file with only a main method and where I want to instantiate an object of `B` to use its methods.

```
#include "b.h"

int main(){
    B obj;
    obj.pure_virtual_method_a();
    return 0;
}
```

**Question 1:** To instantiate an object of `B` in `c.cpp`, do I need to write the header file `b.h` like above? That seems to be so redundant! It looks like interface `A` is so unnecessary :-(

**Question 2:** Is the code presented the right way to implement interface `A`, and use an object of type `B`?

**Question 3:** Do I need to declare a constructor for `B` in `b.h` and implement it in `b.cpp`?

Comment: Did you mean to do `class B : public A`? Side note, you should become familiar with and use the `override` keyword

Comment: The interface A is only necessary if you intend to use the interface polymorphically. Wiith the main function as your present it, A has no reason to exist at all.

Comment: @CoryKramer I didn't understand you question, but what I want to do is implement the interface A methods, calling it as class B and use those implemented methods inside the main function. I will take a look at the override keyword, thanks.

Comment: @CarlosOst Declaring interfaces as `struct` goes more smoothly.

Comment: Thank you Frank for your comment. I see that in this example it is really not necessary, but searching about this subject I found some cases It is, you are right.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Could be, but the actual context forces me to use it like presented. The interface is not mine and I need to use it like this. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I've made an update do talk about the real context. Maybe it helps.

Comment: You made it seem so redundant because you exposed the B class.  Just don't, you need a static factory function that creates a B object and returns the interface type.  Now *all* the B implementation details can be hidden.

Comment: Even if inheritance from `A` is not exposed and polymorphism is not used, `A` still forces `B` to implement those virtual functions so it is not completely wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Question 1*

You miss a semicolon after the closing curly brace, and it is better to specify that the pure virtual methods you implement in `B` are marked as `override`. This allows the compiler to emit warnings in case you forget to change any of the overridden method declarations as soon as the corresponding pure virtual methods in `A` would change. Thus you will end up with:

```
#include "a.h"

struct B : public A {
    void pure_virtual_method_a() override;
    void pure_virtual_method_b() override;
    static int static_method();
};
```

From this it is also clear that for the compiler to be able to declare `B` as a type, `A` needs to be declared as well. For example, how would the compiler check the `override` keyword if it did not yet already have a declaration of `A`. In case you would not have any overridden virtual methods, `A` still needs to be known, since the compiler needs to be able to deduce the size of `B`.

Furthermore, as mentioned in the comments, declaring `B` as a `struct` allows you to drop the `public` keyword, since the default visibility of a `struct` is public in contrast with `private` default visibility for a class. This is the only difference between classes and structs in C++. Thus, for interfaces, using structs is more natural.

*Question 2*

Not completely. **b.cpp** should look something along the following lines:

```
#include "b.h"

void B::pure_virtual_method_a() {/*implementation*/};
void B::pure_virtual_method_b() {/*implementation*/};
int B::static_method() {/*implementation*/};
```

Otherwise, you declare and define three methods in the global namespace, and the linker will complain about undefined references to the three methods of `B` declared in **b.h**.

Furthermore, `B` needs to know how to derive from `A`, either publicly, protected, or private.

Furthermore, it is a good idea to add include guards to the header files, to prevent the compiler from seeing the same type declaration twice when compiling an object file like `a.o` or `b.o`:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"

struct B : public A {
  ...
};

#endif
```

Finally, `static_method()` needs an implementation for `A` as well, static methods can not be virtual.

*Question 3*

You do not need to implement a constructor for `B` necessarily. In case you do not define one, the compiler will generate a default constructor for `B`. However, in case you define a non-default constructor for `A`, you will need to define one for `B` in case you want to construct instances of type `B`. The constructor can be implemented inline in the header file, or can be defined in **b.cpp**.

Comment: Thank you @TonvandenHeuvel . It didn't solve my problem, but your answer is good enough for me. It didn't solve my problem because the actual context have some nuances that I didn't clarified here. It is my fault, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1.

You can use Factory Pattern, then u can add b.h only in Factoru files? and return pointers or smart pointer to A class. For eample, it can be factory function like:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> getObject(/*params*/)
{
    return std::make_unique<B>(/*params*/)
}
```

And then in c.cpp file:

```
auto obj = getObject(/*params*/);
obj->pure_virtual_method_a();
```

Then you can create another implementations of `A` interface, and return them from factory.

Question 2.

should be `class B : public A`

and

```
void B::pure_virtual_method_a() {/*implementation*/};
void B::pure_virtual_method_b() {/*implementation*/};
int B::static_method() {/*implementation*/};
```

Question 3.

If you need constructor in `class A` or constructor exactly for `class B`, you need to define and implement B class constuctor.